# $P[X<np/2]<P[|X−np|>np]$ in binomial distribution $B(n,p)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the original problem, $X$ is binomial distributed, so $E(X)=np$ and $Var(x)=np(1-p)$. The statement said that $Prob[X<np/2]<Prob[|X-np|>(np(1-p))^{1/2}(np/(1-p))^{1/2}]<(1-p)/np$.
The second inequality is an application of Chebyschev inequality. What I don't understand is the first inequality. Could someone tell me where it comes from, or the statement may be wrong and I must have missed something in the paper? Thank you very much!

Thanks to Zubzub for pointing out that my left part is to prove $$P[X<np/2]<P[|X−np|>np]$$ where $X$ follows binomial distribution $B(n,p)$. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Note that 
$
(np(1-p))^{1/2}(np/(1-p))^{1/2} = np
$
So you're left to prove
$
P[X < np/2] < P[|X-np| > np]
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the special case where $n=1$ and $\frac12\leq p<1$.

Then $P(X<\frac{p}2)=P(X=0)=1-p>0$ and $P(|X-p|>p)=0$.

So the statement is not true in general.

We do have:

$$X<\frac{np}2\implies X-np<-\frac{np}2\implies|X-np|>\frac{np}2$$
implying that:$$P(X<\frac{np}2)\leq P(|X-np|>\frac{np}2)$$